# Having an issue for Shopify App listing

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have submitted My app to Shopify App store for review, I got below feedback

```
I was unable to install your app from the App Store listing. I was redirected to this page after clicking 'Get'. When clicking on 'Get' from the app listing, the app should immediately authenticate using OAuth. Please watch this example of what the required installation flow looks like with OAuth when clicking 'Get' from the App Store Listing.
```

How can I resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- When any one click On get button from shopify app store then you must
  have to check that after getting store name it will redirect to your
  link on which you have check store permissions & all other things for
  shopify store. After checking permissions of store it will
  automatically redirect to store OAuth page then you will able to
  install app.

  - You can also check itself where it is redirect when any one click on GET button. Steps for checking:-
  - Login into shopify partner account Go to Apps-> View App Listing. Then you will check by clicking GET button where it is redirect. You have to check conditions & may also you have to set your App Url Link in app which you created in Shopify partner account.
  - You can also these things on Shopify Official documentation.

Please Let me know if you getting issue after try this. I am Happy to help you. Thanks !!